# Spring jdbctemplate not closing connection?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using a Spring jdbcTemplate object like this, to return a result from the database:

```
public class Utils {
...
    @Autowired
    protected JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
...
...
    public Integer getMaxSize(String foo) {
        String query = "SELECT MAX(LENGTH(foo)) AS FF FROM bar";
        Long listSize = (Long)jdbcTemplate.queryForMap(query).get("FF");
        
        if (listSize == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return listSize.intValue();
    }
}
```

```
...
utils.getMaxSize("abc");
```

However, the tomcat connection pool is flagging this as a culprit that's not closing it's connection:

```
  WARNING [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[914504136:1633411205250]] 
  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.abandon Connection has been abandoned 
  PooledConnection[org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection@5b3f016]:java.lang.Exception
  ...
  ...
  at ore.mt.Utils.getMaxSize(Utils.java:725)
  ...
  ...
```

From reading this article: http://fabriziogiovannetti.com/blog/abandoned-connection-on-tomcat-how-to-find-the-root-cause/30

it seems like it's identifying the getMaxSize method as the culprit that's not closing its connection.  In my tomcat connection pool settings, I have:

```
          removeAbandoned="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
          logAbandoned="true"
```

I'm also using:

```
jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer"
```

Is there some edge case I'm not thinking of, where queryForMap itself, or somehow the way I'm returning by reference is somehow keeping the connection open?

Thanks!

Comment: `Utils.getMaxSize` the fact that it is in a `Utils` class makes me wonder how is this thing being used? Is it spring managed or do you create them on the fly or... Please add the actual class.

Comment: Utils (not exact classname in my code, but I greatly simplified here) is a Spring object (in spring application context).  I updated the description above, to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: If this is the actual code there is no leak, so either there is something you aren't showing or tomcat is drunk.

Comment: Are you using the `@Transactional` annotation in the method using your database calls? If not you may want to consider looking into it and using it and is it will handle opening and closing your connections.